# JavaFX TextArea: Listener and event handler dependency

Tags: javafx, event-handling, textarea, handler, changelistener

When I type a character in a TextArea, I want to both handle the event of "new typed character" as well as "cursor position changed". By using the following listener and handler, this works.

```
textArea.selectionProperty().addListener(new SelectionListener());
textArea.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, keyTypedHandler);
```

(SelectionListener implements ChangeListener)

However, when I decide to consume the event in `keyTypedHandler`, the listener's change() method isn't called anymore. For this task I want to consume the event because the textArea's UI should not update!

Any hints appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do. If the UI should not change, then the cursor position will not change, so there would be nothing to handle in the second handler. Can you clarify? And, sort of as an aside, wouldn't it make more sense to register a listener with `textArea.caretPositionProperty()` instead of `textArea.selectionProperty()`?

Comment: Could you explain more about cursor position change? Why do you want to do it?

Comment: Makes sense. I want the event to be triggered without updating the UI. Generally this can be done I think by catching an event and consuming it in the handler, so the event propagation is stopped and the event doesn't reach its target (TextArea). But maybe you pointed already at the problem: If I consume the event, the selectionListener has nothing to handle anymore...

As for your side note, the selectionProperty carries indirectly the caret position and is also updated when the caret is moved. Since I also want selections, this listener handles both cursor updates and selection updates.

Comment: Ok I guess `selectionProperty` is too high level because it works on actual textArea-content which I want to prevent. I should keep track of the cursor and selections with a combination of tracking key and mouse events I suppose.